# Python - Sending data via input boxs

Tags: python

```
data = {'nameofinputbox':'data', 'nameofinputbox2':'data2'}
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.example.com', urllib.urlencode(data))
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

basically what I'm getting it to do is, input subject into subject box and input message into message box, but it doesn't seem to be working.. do I need to add 'nameofsubmitbutton' aswell? or..

Comment: You may or you may not, depending on the site. Double-check that the request URL matches the form action and that you haven't forgotten any hidden inputs.

Comment: it appears the only get data being used is, subject=&message= but you can't manually add that get data into the url and have it successfully submit.. Most of the content is written in Javascript, but it definitely is using GET data, confusing.

Comment: If the method of the form is `GET`, you'll need to append the data to your URL rather than passing it as another parameter to `urllib2.Request`.

Comment: Do you know of anyway for python to select textbox through " name=example " and input data.. without having seleminium ?